# Conditional checkout validations

Tags: magento2

I have created a validation for my checkout field that validates for a number (In our country every house has a number):

[image]

The thing is that sometimes customers would type the house number in the second field:

[image]

But, of course, the first field is still invalid.

I took a look with inspect element and validations are no longer classes that I could remove with JS, like in M1...

How can I make the validation for either of the fields? (So that only one field has to pass the validation)

Comment: This smells of poor implementation.

Comment: I am using a layout processor for address fields,  and each of the fields has its own validation "section". Please, let me know if you have any suggestions on how to implement it better

Comment: I would separate the logic. The address field should have it's own validation and the number field should have also it's own validation.
two separate fields with two separate business logic.